# How to print a range of elements (std::pair<size_t, std::string>) belonging to a map (not all elements)

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, c++17

How can I print a range of elements (key and value) belonging to a `std::map<size_t, std::string>?`

I don't need to print all elements.
Every suggestion using C++11, C++14 or C++17, without boost libraries, is appreciated.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <map>

using namespace std;

void print(map<size_t, string> & m)
{
    for(auto & [key, value] : m)
    {
        cout << setw(6) << left << key << value << endl;
    }
}

void print_range(map<size_t, string> & m, size_t first, size_t last)
{
    // ???
}

int main()
{
    map<size_t, string> data {
                                { 5, "guitar" },
                                { 8, "saxophone" },
                                { 28, "trumpet" },
                                { 32, "trombone" },
                                { 42, "violin" },
                                { 45, "viola" },
                                { 48, "cello" },
                                { 52, "double bass" },
                                { 100, "piano" },
                                { 104, "drum" }
                             };

    print(data);
    print_range(data, 42, 52);    // ???

    return 0;
}
```

The expected output is:

```
42  violin
45  viola
48  cello
52  double bass
```

Comment: It is not clear what "print a range" means. What is your expected output, in this case?

Comment: Print a range of elements of the map (std::pair<key, value>)

Answer (score 8):

Use [`std::map::lower_bound()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/lower_bound) and [`std::map::upper_bound()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/upper_bound)

```
auto p = make_pair(data.lower_bound(42), data.upper_bound(52));
for (auto [begin, end] = p; begin != end; begin++) {
  std::cout << begin->first << " " << begin->second << '\n';
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't understand...... why don't you compare directly?

```
void print_range(map<size_t, string> & m, size_t first, size_t last)
{
    for(auto & kvp : m)
    {
        if (kvp.first >= first && kvp.first <= last)
            cout << setw(6) << kvp.first << ":" << kvp.second << endl;
    }
}
```

I tried... works no problem.

Comment: It works. but it could be more efficient as it traverses the entire map.

Answer (score 2):

`std::for_each` is a good fit for this, for example:

```
void print_range(map<size_t, string> & m, size_t first, size_t last)
{
    auto from = m.lower_bound (first);
    auto to = m.upper_bound (last);
    std::for_each (from, to, [] (const auto &e)
        { std::cout << e.first << ' ' << e.second << '\n'; });
}
```

[Live demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/85VSl1sssaHbjgUA)